# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION

Tags: android

I know this question is already asked but those answers are not helpful.

I am getting below error on some specific device like samsung tab 3, and it is running fine on samsung galaxy s3 mobile.

I want to run my application on all the device which supports google play service. There are other application which includes gcm and running well on samsung tab 3.

My manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
<!--
     The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
     to target higher versions.
-->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Main activity. -->
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
      BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
      services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

      The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
      so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

My error log:-

```
    09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gcm.demo.app/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkReceiver(GCMRegistrar.java:184)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:169)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:54)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
09-22 13:03:06.625: E/AndroidRuntime(22439):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: It's in the same package. I also said that the app is running in other device. If problem is regarding wrong package name than how come it is working on other device.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem when my device was running on the safe mode !! - This information might be helpful to you..

Comment: The person who downvoted my question please tell me the reason in what way my question was inappropriate? Have you even read my question properly?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the receiver to recieve GCM callbacks.

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="smart.emergencyservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="smart.emergencyservice.GCMIntentService" />
```

and then make GCMIntentService extending GCMBaseIntentService

Comment: I have implemented it, and its running well on some tablet. Its not working on some specific tablets.

Comment: You require a gmail account associated with tablet if its running android 4.0.3 or low for devices running on 4.0.4 or higher it will work fine.

Comment: I have gmail account associated in my tablet. I am getting this issue in Samsung galaxy tab 3 and not on nexus 7, both have gmail account and above 4.0.4 OS